# Using Custom Classes in Collection Types using DataStax's Java Driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

Is there a way to use our types (classes we provide) in the the collection types that we provide to the DataStax Java Driver through the `BoundStatement.setSet(..)` method without using User Defined Types? Perhaps with the Object Mapping API?

And if so, when we create the table what  should we use for the **type** in the `SET` (in other words: `SET<????>`)?

We're using the DataStax Java Driver v2.1.5 connected to DSE v4.6.0 (Cassandra 2.0.11.83).

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE teams (uid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, players SET<????>);
```

Our Type:

```
public class Player {

  private String name;

  public Player(String name) { this.name = name;   }

  public String getName() { return name;   }    
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

}
```

Test:

```
public void testSets(){

    Set<Player> players = new HashSet<>();

    players.add(new Player("Nick"));
    players.add(new Player("Paul"));
    players.add(new Player("Scott"));

    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO teams (uid, players) values (?,?);");

    BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);

    boundStatement.setString("uid", ...);
    boundStatement.setSet("players", players);

    session.execute(boundStatement);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this today with the driver or its object mapping API yet.  There is an outstanding issue ([JAVA-722](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-722)) opened today to handle this and other mapping related inadequacies (related issues linked in that issue) that will be covered in the next release (2.1.6) of the driver.

It may also be worth taking a look at [Achilles](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles) which supports this through its [Type Transformer](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/Type-Transformer).